# PHP Checkbox delete files from folder

Tags: php, checkbox, delete-file

I want to delete files from folder called "fajlovi". Multiple and singled delete should work. But it delete first file in folder (0 position in array of files in the folder). If I check any for files it will delete first 4 files instead files I checked. Here is the code:

```
    $a = glob("fajlovi/*");
    echo "<br>var_dump of \$a ------------------------<br><pre>";
    var_export($a);
    echo "</pre>end dump od \$a ------------------------<br><br>";
    echo "Number od files in the directory: " . count($a) . "<br>";

    echo "<form method='POST' action='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "'><table >";
    echo "<th>File name:</th><th>Size MB:</th><th>Delete:</th>";
    foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $value . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . round(filesize($value) / 1024 / 1024, 5) . " MB <br></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checked[]'>" . $img_number = $key + 1 . "</td>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td colspan=3><input type='submit' name='delete' value='Delete'></td></tr>";
    echo "</table></form>";


    if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        $checkbox = $_POST['checked'];
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($a); $i++) {
            if (isset($checkbox[$i])) {
                if (unlink($a[$i])) {
                    echo "Successfully deleted file" . $a[$i] . "<br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['checked'])) {
        var_dump($_POST['checked']);
    }
```

***1. This is screenshot of the page:***

[image]

***2.then I check images I want to delete:***

[image]

***3. After pressing Delete button, this is the result:***
[image]

***4. And after entering the page again, we can see that wrong images are deleted:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your inputs a value

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checked[]' value='{$key}'>
```

Here's some code to bump you in the right direction.

```
$files = glob('fajlovi/*');
$indicesToDelete = array_intersect((array)($_POST['checked'] ?? []), array_keys($files));

foreach ($indicesToDelete as $index) {
  if (unlink($files[$index])) {
      echo "Successfully deleted file" . $files[$index] . "<br>";
  }
}
```

---

I wouldn't be implementing the deletion like this though. Instead of using the indexes provided by `glob()` as your method of locating files to delete, you should be using a key that *uniquely and definitively identifies* the file. At the very least this means using **the filepath** itself. Consider for example a scenario in which file(s) are added ore removed between when your form displays and you make and submit your selections for deletion. You could end up removing the wrong files.

Instead you might pass the filepath here:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='checked[]' value='{$value}'>
```

And then work with them instead of indices.

```
$files = glob('fajlovi/*');
$pathsToDelete = array_intersect((array)($_POST['checked'] ?? []), $files);

foreach ($pathsToDelete as $filepath) {
  if (unlink($filepath)) {
      echo "Successfully deleted file" . $files[$index] . "<br>";
  }
}
```

As a final bit of advice:

- You should check `file_exists()`, `is_file()`, or similar before doing the unlink. You should be doing everything you can to ensure you're only allowing the deletion of the files you intended.

Comment: I'm still learning PHP, so I don't understand this line this part "?? []," of the line: array_intersect($_POST['checked'] ?? [], array_keys($files)). Could you explain me that? Thanks

Comment: The `??` is a [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op). That chunk of code says "if $_POST doesn't have a 'checked' property, default to an empty array instead. Regardless, ensure we're passing _an_ array into `array_intersect()`".  This avoids some of your nested conditionals and setup for loops.

Comment: Also, the whole `array_intersect()` line is effectively filtering out bad data from `$_POST['checked']`. It's ensuring `$pathsToDelete` contains __only__ valid values for you to loop over, or _nothing_.

Comment: [] - is this an empty string or checked image? Thanx

Comment: It's shorthand array syntax. Its equivalent to `array()`.